# Get row and column number from file C

Tags: c, file, row, col

i have a .txt file I want to read from in C. Every character should be a col and every line a row.
I want to store the number of rows and columns in an int variable.
I did it like this. My rows numbers are correct, but my columns are 0.

```
...

int rows_i = 0;
int cols_i = 0, cols = 0;

FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if (file) {
        while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
            if (c == '\n') {            
                break;
            }else if (c !='\0') {         
                rows_i++;
            } else {
                cols_i++;
                if(cols_i> cols){
                    cols = cols_i;
                    cols_i = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        printf("No such file!");
        return ...;
    }
....
```

Any idea why that is?

My output of rows is correct. Output for cols is always 0.

Comment: What is the logic behind columns? Is every character a column? Or is every space separated value a column? What is the initial value of `cols`?

Comment: Yes every character is a column. Initial value of cols is 0

Comment: Is the above code always returning 1 for `cols`?

Comment: returning 0 for cols

Comment: the txt file contains a cube with lot of +++
I need to get the rows and cols so I can do some calculation

Comment: @yoggozuna Please [edit] your question and add all clarification or requested information there instead of answering in comments. Add enough code that we can compile and run it. Show some example input and the expected and actual output corresponding to this input.

Comment: You're incrementing `rows_i` for every non-null `c`.

Comment: The "cube" probably is a square... ;)

Comment: yeah ;) more or less

Answer (score 1):

Your output is correct according to your code. There's not any error in that. Look here:-

```
while ((c = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
            if (c == '\n') {            
                break;
            }else if (c !='\0') {         
                rows_i++;
            } else {
                cols_i++;
                if(cols_i> cols){
                    cols = cols_i;
                    cols_i = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

In line `else if (c !='\0') rows_i++;` you are incrementing `rows_i++` for each character which is not *null character*. If you want to count `rows` and `cols` then modify this section:-

```
if (c == '\n') {            
                break;
            }else if (c !='\0') {         
                rows_i++;
            } else {
                cols_i++;
                if(cols_i> cols){
                    cols = cols_i;
                    cols_i = 0;
                }
            }
```

to

```
if( c == '\n')
 rows_i++;
else
 cols_i++;
```

**Update:** If you want to count how many columns in each row then use `fgets()` to read a line and then `strlen()` to find the number of `char` in that line.

Consider this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int rows = 0;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    char buffer[1000] = {'\0'};

    if ( file )
    {
        while( fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file) != NULL)
            printf("Row %d\tCols %d\n", ++rows, strlen(buffer));
    }
    else
    {
        printf("There's no such file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

In this program we are getting `a` line from the file and storing it into `buffer`. Then we are printing its row no. , which will increment by 1 after each loop, and printing its columns no., which will always be equal to the no. of characters in that line. `strlen` will count each character except `'\0'`.

Comment: The output of the rows are correct now. But for the columns it gives me the total number of length instead of the number of columns per row.

Comment: Assume there are 15 ```chars``` each in 2 lines in your text file then,  it'll show you ```Rows = 2 & Cols = 30``` then where's the problem? @yoggozuna

Comment: if you want to know the columns per row then print it while counting, in ```while``` loop.

Comment: Ok ! I didn't understand your question. But now, I updated my answer check it out. @yoggozuna